# How to remove syncronized photos from facebook

Tags: facebook, gallery, samsung-galaxy-note-2

I have a Galaxy Note II and I syncronized my Facebook gallery by mistake. I've tried to disactivate the sync from the Settings (Settings > Account) by unchecking the "Sync gallery" option but the photos still remain in the phone gallery. I can't even remove them from gallery beacuse there's no option shown. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unckecking the `Sync gallery` will not remove the albums.

Just uninstall `Facebook` application from your phone. This will remove all your Facebook albums from the stock gallery.

Upon reinstalling Facebook, don't forget to uncheck `Sync gallery`.

This did the trick for me :)

Answer (score 3):

Just in case somebody stumbles upon this question - you don't need to uninstall Facebook. Just open the Gallery, press the menu button and go to "Content to display" option. Uncheck Facebook there. Done.

Comment: but like this you cannot remove the photos, you just hide them.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall Facebook. Then go to `Settings > Application Manager > All > Gallery > Clear Data`.